# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on using spring security on google app engine

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-security

I am using Spring Core framework version 4.1.6.RELEASE and Spring Security version 4.0.0.RELEASE in my google app. But when I try to run it in local appservere I see following log

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.reflect.Parameter is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
```

Then I checked that in which jdk version this `java.lang.reflect.Parameter` class was introduced and found that it is there since 1.8. But app engine supports java 1.7 only. How could I find the spring framework versions which are build on 1.7 JDK. Please suggest

Comment: Spring support java support is from 6 to 8. It uses annotation to know what kind of new feature should we use depending of your source and target level. See https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/03/how-spring-achieves-compatibility-with-java-6-7-and-8. Do you build your application using `-source 1.7 -target 1.7`?

Comment: yes I use maven compile plugin with source and target as 1.7

Comment: No idea but maybe more chance here https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2324

Answer (score 5):

You have to download the JDK7 and it will work. I had the same problem.

Comment: Thanks I was using Eclipse's default JDK 1.8 and I just had to define a new JDK 1.7 under Eclipse preferences Java/InstalledJre and checked it as the default.