# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.reflect.Parameter is a restricted class

Tags: google-app-engine

When changed to JRE to JDK 1.8.0, Not able to get the server started. It compiled fine.  Note, this application runs fine with JRE 1.7

I'm using SDK App Engine - 1.9.71

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0':
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   java.lang.reflect.Parameter is a restricted class. Please see the
>   Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:478)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
>     ... 61 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   java.lang.reflect.Parameter is a restricted class. Please see the
>   Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.    at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:65)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:182)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:243)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:988)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
>     ... 66 more

Comment: You are using Java 1.7? Looks like Parameter is not in the [whitelist](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/jrewhitelist?csw=1) and thus, not allowed

Answer (score 0):

You say in your question:

"I'm using SDK App Engine - 1.9.34"

App Engine SDK 1.9.34 is an [old version](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/release-notes#1.9.34) base on Java 7 that doesn't support Java 8.

Try with a newer App Engine SDK version.

Comment: a little confused, i using App Engine SDK 1.9.71

Comment: Can you please clarify the App Engine SDK that you are using? Because in your question you mention `1.9.34` and now you are mentioning `1.9.71`. Also this application can't run on JRE 1.7, because the method `java.lang.reflect.Parameter` that you are currently using, is only available in `JRE 1.8` as it is specified in [Class Parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html). Please note tough, that this is not an official Google documentation.

Comment: i using SDK 1.9.71

Comment: Can you also please confirm with me if you are trying to run the server on JRE 1.7 or JRE 1.8 ?

Comment: i using JRE  1.7, Currently I need to upgrade to 1.8 because google cloud  not supports java 7

Comment: After upgrading to JRE 1.8, I encountered this error, I found many similar questions but did not have an answer to this problem.

Comment: The error is coming from `java.lang.reflect.Parameter is a restricted class.`. It seems that this method is no longer supported in JRE 1.8 therefore you have to use JRE 1.7 in your case. In this question [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on using spring security on google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769096/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-on-using-spring-security-on-google-app-engine), you can see the same error as yours and the answer is to use JDK7.

Comment: Google Cloud can't support Java 7on January 16, 2019, so I have to upgrade to java 8.